# Apache Server redirection issue on .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have written HTML page and want to set RewriteRule. I have created .htaccess file into the folder written these:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test.html [QSA,L]
```

It just redirects to http://example.com/test.html . I want to redirection to http://localhost/project/test

I think it is caused by httpd.conf or hosts file. But I can't find a way.

Edit: .htaccess file is under C:\xampp\htdocs\project

Thank you.

Comment: An _internal_ redirection does not rewrite to URLs, but only to paths. Question is what you actually want. Rewriting to `/project/test` does not really make sense...

Comment: Ok, I want to paths

Comment: That does not help. From _what_ incoming URL to _what_ internal path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this rule with appropriate `RewriteBase` value:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ test.html [L]
```

Comment: Interesting... You post an answer with the question being that unclear?

Comment: @sundowatch: Where is this .htaccess located and what URL did you use to test?

Comment: Ok. I looked for the virtual hosts.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why do you want to use .htaccess file for redirect. Also note You can not move your site to localhost. You may directly do from your file

```
String site="/abc.com/test.html"
Response.setStatus(response.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY)
Response.setHeader("Location", site);
```

Comment: for testing purpose you may use your localhost address in the site variable as mentioned above

Comment: @ASingh Where do you suggest to apply the commands you suggest? What language are they in?

Comment: Jap file (java)